# Register Route and javascript problem

Tags: asp.net

I registered a Route in my route table in the global asax file. When I load the page it loads normally without the new route and my menu works fine, but when i enter in the new url for the route it gives me a javascript error(object expected) for my jquery menu. error is on the

```
document.ready(function() {})
```

i've tried changing the order of my scripts but i still get the same problem no matter what. 
Im using a master page for my ShowProducts page. When i view the source and have a look at the links to my scripts they still point to the directory where they reside. When you change the url to the mapped route does the url change for the source of the script files.

Comment: I found out part of the problem it is the url or path to the script and css files that have changed. The browser is asking for the full url e.g /WebSite2/Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js. I have another problem now for my style sheets for the images cos now the path has changed. how do resolve the url for style sheets. I can't change the path to /WebSite2/images/ what do i do this scenario

Comment: And does any one know how to get the url for website like http://localhost:2222/WebSite2 in cluding the http:// that would be helpful.